# このXPathはLINQ to XMLならどう書くのでしょうか？

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, xpath

初歩的な質問ですみません．普段XPathしか使っていません．LINQ to XMLを使用した場合、次のXPathと同等の結果を得るにはどう書いたら良いのでしょうか？

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.XPath
Imports Sgml
...
Dim sgml As SgmlReader = New SgmlReader()
sgml.DocType = "HTML"
sgml.Href = "http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/data/mdrr/synopday/data1s.html"
sgml.IgnoreDtd = True
Dim htmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(sgml)
Dim nsTable As NameTable = New NameTable
Dim nsMgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(nsTable)
nsMgr.AddNamespace("xhtml", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
Dim targetTrs As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = htmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("//xhtml:table[@class = 'o1']//xhtml:tr[@class != 'o1h']", nsMgr)
```

気象庁の気象データから地点毎の最高気温を取得しようとしています．このプログラムはなんとか動きましたが、LINQで書けばどうなるのかがよくわかりません．

以上 よろしくお願いします．

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual BasicではXML対応しているため、別の記述が可能です。
まず、XML名前空間については[Import構文](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb384589.aspx)で指定可能です。

```vb
Imports <xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

次に`//xhtml:table`については[XML子孫軸プロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb384876.aspx)で指定可能です。

```vb
Dim htmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(sgml)
Dim targetTables As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = htmlDoc...<xhtml:table>
```

次に`[@class = 'o1']`については`Where`を使えますがその際[XML属性軸プロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb384755.aspx)が使えます。

```vb
Dim targetTables As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = htmlDoc...<xhtml:table> _
    .Where(Function(e) e.@class = "o1")
```

最後に[クエリ構文](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb384830.aspx)を使用することでシンプルになります。

```vb
Imports <xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
Dim htmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(sgml)
Dim targetTrs As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
    From table In htmlDoc...<xhtml:table> _
    Where table.@class = "o1" _
    From tr In table...<xhtml:tr> _
    Where tr.@class <> "o1h" _
    Select tr
```

---

なお、pgrhoさんの回答のXName.Getですが、XML名前空間を別途指定する２引数バージョンの他に、XML名前空間を含むXML名を指定することができる[１引数バージョン](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb357369(v=vs.110).aspx)も存在します。その上で、[文字列からXNameへの暗黙の型キャスト](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit(v=vs.110).aspx)も用意されているため

```vb
d.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}table") _
...
```

と記述できます。この方法はC#言語でも使用でき便利です。

Comment: クエリーでFrom/Whereの入れ子というのはWEBを当たっていても気が付きませんでした．こちらの方がXPathやっていてSQLも少しは知っているレベルの立場からすると身近でわかりやすいですね．勉強になりました．

Comment: @tmakita さん、クエリ構文の説明へリンクしました。その中で[From句](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb384802.aspx)の解説ではFrom句を入れ子・ネストする方法についても言及されています。

Comment: @ sayuri さん、クエリ構文の説明拝見しました．今まで何故このようなページを探し当てられなかったのかと思います...！

Answer (score 4):

XPathの`//`はXLINQの`Descendants`拡張メソッドに対応します。この場合はXML名前空間が設定されているので`XName`を明示的に作成する必要があります。
`[]`にはLINQの`Where`を使用し、`XElement.Attribute`メソッドで属性を取得します。

```
Dim d = XDocument.Parse(html)

Dim targetTrs = d.Descendants(XName.Get("table", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")) _
                     .Where(Function(e) e.Attribute("class")?.Value = "o1") _
                 .Descendants(XName.Get("tr", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")) _
                     .Where(Function(e) e.Attribute("class")?.Value <> "o1h")
```

Comment: predicateは.whereでそのように書くのですね．大変勉強になりました！